# How to show single instance of element using CSS?

Tags: html, css

EDIT:The problem is i am using react so i cannot wrap these elements using another div because they have many parents. Is there any way to look every div in the page which have class .my-class and show last instance of it.

I want to change the background color of the last div instance. In code div which contains 'third'.

https://jsfiddle.net/a694du2h/

But the first div becomes red too. I know it is because they do not have the same parent. Is there any way to do what I want?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .my-class:last-of-type {
      background: #ff0000;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div class='my-class'>first</div>
  </div>
  <div class='my-class'>second</div>
  <div class='my-class'>third</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Will your first/second/third items always have the same structure, or can each of them be inside wrapping `div`s?

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't think this is a duplicate of the question you've linked.

Comment: It is. The question is based on a misunderstanding of the "power" of `nth`. The OP wants `last-of-class` and there is **no such selector**.

Answer (score 0):

Bind your rule to those classes that are immediately below the body parent.

```
body > .my-class:last-of-type {
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/760Ljbca/

Comment: I cannot wrap these elements using another div because they have many parents. Is there any way to look every div in the page which have class .my-class and show last instance of it.

Comment: This isn't wrapping in a div, it's using the natural parent in your example.  There is no other way to select the "last" of a class (see comment on question from @paulie_d).  You could use javascript to dynamically evaluate the DOM for the last class, or emit a "special" class in react.